# Integrating an infinite-valued function over a zero length interval

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Let $\delta(t)$ be defined as the limit of a Gaussian pdf with 'zero variance'.
What is then the result of $$I=\int_0^0 \delta(t)dt\quad?$$

on the one hand, "$\delta(0)=\infty$", but the length of the interval is zero. I think that since $\delta$ is defined by a limit, whereas the interval is zero (without a limit), then the integral will be zero, but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: The Dirac delta function is a "generalized" function. It is defined to have integral 1 over any interval that includes 0.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you want to define/use this? The $\delta$ distribution (which is what you get in your limit) is usually defined as a linear functional on some space and not via integrals like this. I ask, since I think this situation looks quite unnatural. Maybe there is some limit involved in the zeroes of the limits in the integral?

Comment: This question stems from my previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834383/double-dirac-delta-integral that hasn't got any responses. I thought focusing on the main part (which is the overlap in zero) might be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Without the limit, it's undefined, because it's an improper integral which can be assigned a value only as a limit of well-defined integrals.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between "zero variance" and "limit when variance goes to zero". Try computing the limit

$$\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\int_{-\omega}^{\omega}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{t^2/2\sigma^2} dt$$

The answer is

$$\lim_{\sigma\to 0^+} erf\bigg(\frac{\omega}{\sigma\sqrt{2}} \bigg) = 1 ^*$$

which is what you expect when you integrate the Dirac delta function $\delta(t-t_0)$ over the interval $-\omega<t_0<\omega$:

$$\int_{-\omega}^{\omega}\delta(t-t_0)dt = 1 $$

$^*$ Notice that I put $\lim_{\sigma\to 0^+}$, because the variance is a positive quantity and thus the limit is taken from the right. The limit from the left of this error function would be -1, but again, the variance is positive and this would make no sense.

Comment: It is indeed a limit, but what happens when omega, the interval length, approaches zero as well? Is the result still 1 in the limit?

Comment: Just put $\lim_{\omega\to 0}$ outside the integral and see what happens. They key is that in the limit $\sigma\to 0$, the integral is independent of $\omega$, and thus you can make it as small as you what.

Comment: The question is how to calculate this double limit. I'm not sure how it's done.